# Unused space in FOR XML Path?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have a table `Category` with three columns `ID (int), Name (nchar 150), Description (nchar 500)`, when i try to convert to xml using this sql query `SELECT * FROM [CATEGORY] FOR XML PATH`, i get this result:

```
<idCat>1</idCat>
<CatName>Cat 1 ... 100 space character </CatName>
<CatDesc>Desc 1 ... 500 space character </CatDesc>
```

Comment: Why are you using `nchar` instead of `nvarchar`?

Comment: If am not wrong you have clean up all the space characters before passing to `for xml path`.. no other way.. Use `Replace` function with `char(n)` to replace the space characters

Comment: @Pரதீப் `RTRIM`. Though fixing the schema of the source table seems warranted.

Comment: @Pரதீப் They are space characters added on to pad out to 150 and 500 characters.

Comment: run a update with `Description = rtrim(Description)` then try again

Comment: Thank you so much it worked :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the source table definition.

Your names and descriptions clearly aren't fixed lengths in reality so you shouldn't be using fixed length datatypes. They will be padded out with trailing spaces to fill the declared length. This means that each row is consuming 1,300 bytes for those two columns even if the actual values are much shorter.

Change the `nchar` columns to `nvarchar` and remove the trailing spaces that have been added by running an update statement using `rtrim` on both columns.

```
UPDATE Category 
SET Name = RTRIM(Name), Description = RTRIM(Description)
```

Comment: This is the first time i use `For XML Path` clause, i always thought that nchar or nvarchar we can set the max length but the space used will be only the one that is actually used. Thank you so much for your time. :D